# Not able to instantiate a context from all project within a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, nuget

I have a solution where there are following projects:

1. a context and entities developed under code-first approach.
2. A class library that present some business objects. the objets are using the EF context and its object for a DataAccess needs.
3. The solution has unit test of the business objects

I am able to execute my unit test successfully.

Now I have added a MVC 5 project where I would like to inject my business object. I have created a controller and view and put the same peace of code which has been passed in one of my unit test and also added the project web config proper entity framework and connnection strings sections.  When I am executing the code I am facing the follwing error:

> Migrations is enabled for context 'DatabaseContext' but the database
>   does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create
>   the database and its tables, for example by running the
>   'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

When I am debugging my code I see that I am getting throug theese instructions

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ModelContextStrategy());
```

and

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}
```

but still my result is negative, although everething works fine in my unit testss...

in case I am doing the unit tests first the db is get created and all unit test are through, and then I am starting the MVC application I am getting:

> The model backing the 'DatabaseContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

What I am missing or doing wrong? (specific nuget packages installation for the mvc project? )

Comment: If it is possible try to delete your database.

Comment: in my case I have no database, so I expect the db to be created

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved as soon a I enabled the entity framework for my MVC project

> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.0